# RTSP/RTP load balancing. Possible?

Tags: video-streaming, load-balancing, rtsp, rtp

I have an idea how to implement rtp streaming from few server's to one client (for load balancing).

First of all, client connected to rtsp server to port 554.

Client sends SETUP command, and now we know what ports for rtp will be using.

```
SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.16/movie.mp4 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=41760-41761
```

Than player send

```
PLAY rtsp://192.168.1.16/movie.mp4 RTSP/1.0
```

and server start sending RTP packets to this port  what be using for rtp.

If rtp packets sends over UDP, can I (from server side) stream RTP from one server to client  IP/port then send client IP/port to the second server, and continue RTP stream from the second server to client and so on?

Would it work ?

Answer (score 2):

Just a few quick (by no means comprehensive) points:

- Your approach would break both RTP and RTCP: How would you synchronise sending of packets between the different servers both from a timing (when to send which packet) and sequence number perspective?
- You would break RTCP reporting as you now have different paths that the packets are sent over. How would you handle RTCP reporting? To both servers? To one server? This is all non-standard behaviour. One thing that may be if interest to you is [Multipath RTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-singh-avtcore-mprtp-08) which is currently under standardisation.
- It makes more sense to me to perform load balancing on a per user basis. First user is redirected to RTSP server 1, user number 2 to RTSP server 2, etc. Users may be redirected to an appropriate RTSP server based on location, server load, server bandwidth, etc.